# Asserting exception in FsUnit F# for XUnit

Tags: f#, fsunit

I am trying to assert that an exception was thrown.  Here is a cut down piece of code that reproduces the problem:

```
open FsUnit
open Xunit

let testException () =
    raise <| Exception()

[<Fact>]
let ``should assert throw correctly``() =
    (testException ())
        |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

The error says that a System.Exception was thrown but the test should pass as that is what I am asserting.  Can someone please help with where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the `testException` function, and then passing its result as argument to the `should` function. At runtime, `testException` crashes, and so never returns a result, and so the `should` function is never called.

If you want the `should` function to catch and correctly report the exception, you need to pass it the `testException` function itself, not its result (for there is no result in the first place). This way, the `should` function will be able to invoke `testException` within a `try..with` block and thus catch the exception.

```
testException |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

Comment: makes sense to what I was doing wrong however I have just tried that and now I get a MatchException where it was says Expected: System.Exception, Actual: was was "SqlJuxtFunctionalTests.Tests.TableBuilder.PrimaryKeyTests+should throw an exception when try to build a table with a clustered primary key referencing a nullable column@116" which I believe is the name of my function so it feels like the whole function is being match to Exception, the function is not being executed

Comment: I think you may be misrepresenting your problem. What's the signature of your function? How exactly are you passing it? Please show your actual code.

Comment: signature of testException function is unit->a' Code is: ```let testException () =
            raise <| System.Exception()

        [<Fact>]
        let ``should assert throw correctly``() =
            testException |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``should assert throw correctly``() =
    (fun () -> Exception() |> raise |> ignore)
        |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

Not really sure why the ignore is required tbh. Not found anything to explain this.